# Programmatically adding References to Outlook 2010 in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have a macro for Outlook that, in part, edits the content of an email or calendar item, which requires that the "Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library" Reference is added.  I know how to do this in Excel `ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid()`, but I can't find any information on doing this in Outlook.

Is it possible?

Sample code per Remou:

```
Sub CreateNotesEmailFromAppointment()
  Dim oMeeting As AppointmentItem
  Dim oEmailTemplate As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim oEmailWordDoc As Word.Document

  If Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Class = olAppointment Then
    Set oMeeting = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set oEmailTemplate = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(PathToTemplateFile)
    oEmailTemplate.Display
    Set oEmailWordDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor

    With oEmailWordDoc.Content.Find
        .Text = "<Date>"
        .Replacement.Text = Month(oMeeting.Start) & "/" & Day(oMeeting.Start)
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    'More editing and formatting of oEmailWordDoc follows'
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code runs for me with an Outlook template when I change `Dim oEmailWordDoc As Word.Document` to `Dim oEmailWordDoc As Object`

Comment: Interesting.  When I already have the Word object library reference enabled this works fine.  However, when I don't have the Word object library reference, the sub doesn't execute at all (ex. I put a debug.print line as the first line and it didn't execute).  I wonder if this has something to do with my version of Outlook (2010, 64-bit)?

Comment: I tested with 2013 64 bit and I can't imagine it is that much different. I may have time to look again in a bit.

Comment: Yes, interesting. If the Word library exists, then the replace happens, otherwise no replace.

Comment: I have added a note on a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider late binding:

```
Dim wd As Object

Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wd.Visible = True
wd.Documents.Open "C:\Docs\Temp.doc"
```

If an instance of Word may be running:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set wd = GetObject(,"Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
   Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

wd.Visible = True
```

This is for 2002, but is a better reference that the more recent ones: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307216

How about a different approach that does not use word but rather the HTMLBody of the template:

```
  Dim oMeeting As AppointmentItem
  Dim oEmailTemplate As Outlook.MailItem

  If Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Class = olAppointment Then
    Set oMeeting = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set oEmailTemplate = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(PathToTemplateFile)
    oEmailTemplate.Display
    oEmailTemplate.HTMLBody = _
       Replace(oEmailTemplate.HTMLBody, "&lt;date&gt;", Month(oMeeting.Start) _
          & "/" & Day(oMeeting.Start))
  End If
```

Comment: Thanks Remou - but this isn't working for me.  I need to Dim objects as (for example) a Word.Document object, but I'm using Outlook.Inspector.WordEditor to set that object to a value.  When I remove the Word object library from the References, the sub/functions don't run.

Comment: Post some parts of a sample sub.

Comment: And that works - thanks!  Not exactly what I was looking for when I asked the question, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could find Outlook VBA does not allow this for security reasons. Perhaps creating an Add-In would be a solution.